# Confused as to what changing the internal process of the OS is

Tags: rootkits

I am a highschool student taking TestOut's Ethical Hacker Pro. Currently I am learning about rootkits and [Sirefef](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-sirefef-malware-153453). When explaining Sirefef, it says:

> Sirefef hides itself by altering the internal processes of an
>   operating system so that your antivirus and anti-spyware can't detect
>   it.

I'm not sure what this means. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: A little digging will get you to the technical details of any malware: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Win32/Sirefef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schroeder posted a great resource for learning about common malware. To answer your question directly using the link he provided:

> Sirefef tries to stop and delete the following security-related
>   services:
>
> - Base Filtering Engine Service (bfe) IP Helper Service (iphlpsvc)
> - Windows Defender Service (windefend) Windows Firewall Service (mpssvc)
> - Windows Security Center Service (wscsvc) Windows Firewall Windows
> - Update Multiple other services, including PolicyAgent, Program
> - Compatibility Assistant Service (pcasvc), and RemoteAccess

and

> Sirefef tries to turn off Windows Firewall to make sure its own traffic won’t be blocked.